# Want to create new Project in IBM Watson

Tags: ibm-watson

I have an account with IBM watson studio. I want to create project. But on the homepage not getting an option to create project. Kindly help to get that option.

I tried to open a support case but able to open as it is prompting an error message

Need to create project

Answer (score 2):

it is sometimes painful. Basically, [https://cloud.ibm.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSGFv.png) sign in here. Then on the homepage or dashboard; you will see Create Resource +
Click on it. You will see IBM Cloud Products. Just select Watson Studio and then everything is as you want or as you see on the tutorial videos.
[image]

[image]

After you select Watson Studio, Select your region, elect your plan, write a service name then on the right hand side click to Create.
If you are using free plan, you may not see create button. If so, on the homepage, click hamburger menu and click resource list. There is a list with bunch of cloud services. Find your active service and delete it(see picture below). Then you are good to go. Follow the first steps.[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the homepage you are on? You should be on something that has a url looking like https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/home?context=wdp

From there you should be able to see two options - 'Create a project' and 'New project'

If you can't see the 'New project' option, then you may not have added any Studio services yet. You need to add services, as the new project options are based on the services that you have added.